Can Sleep Function In C be set to something between 0 and 1 in Windows OS?
The following code in C works perfectly fine. sleep(n) in C takes the argument n as integer, the pattern so produced by the code is fast and at sleep(1) is very slow. I want to go with something in between maybe like sleep(0.5). Is there someway to do it ????? I have Windows OS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <direct.h>

void main()
{
    char ch='*';
    int i=0;bool flag=true;
    while(0<i<10)
    {
        if(flag)
        {
            ++i;
            for(int j=0;j<i;j++) //For increaing-pattern
            {
                printf("%c",ch);
            }
            printf("\n");
            if(i==10)
            {
                sleep(1);
                flag=!flag;
            }
        }
        else if(!flag)
        {
            --i;
            for(int j=i;j>-1;j--) //For increaing-pattern
            {
                printf("%c",ch);
            }
            printf("\n");
            if(i==0)
            {
                sleep(1);
                flag=!flag;
            } 
        }
    }
}

As mentioned before the program is printing way too fast, and way too slow at sleep(1).

Use the Windows Sleep function which uses time values in milliseconds.

There is no function sleep in the C language. There is one in *nix which takes seconds as parameter and a different one in Windows called Sleep which takes milliseconds as parameter. You seem to be confusing these.

On UNIX/Linux you could use nanosleep or usleep to sleep for less than a second.

Even wuth the proper sleep functions from the answer bellow you won't get consistent results  with very small intervals because of the OS scheduling. If the sleep interval is very small you can do a spin lock instead. I.e. while (elapsed_time < sleep_time) update_elapsed_time();

On Windows:
#include <windows.h>

void delay( unsigned long ms )
{
  Sleep( ms );
}

On *nixen / POSIX:
#include <time.h>

void delay( unsigned long ms )
{
  struct timespec t = { .tv_sec = ms / 1000, .tv_nsec = (ms % 1000) * 1000000 };
  nanosleep( &t, NULL );
}

Invoke with the number of milliseconds to sleep. Half a second would be 500:
delay( 500 );

N.B.
As Jonathan Leffler kindly pointed out in comments, the following has been deprecated and removed from POSIX:

#include <unistd.h>

void delay( unsigned long ms )
{
  usleep( ms * 1000 );
}



Note that as of POSIX 2024, usleep() is no longer officially a part of POSIX.  It was marked obsolescent in prior versions — you have to go back to POSIX 2004 to find usleep().  The replacement is nanosleep().

@JonathanLeffler Honestly, it has been such a long time since I’ve even wanted to use such a function that I didn’t know. It looks to me like nanosleep() is the POSIX version of WaitForSingleObject()?

Since WaitForSingleObject() takes an object handle and nanosleep() doesn't, the match is imperfect.  The second argument to nanosleep() reports the amount of time left on the sleep if nanosleep() returns because it is interrupted.  Useful information, but quite different from the handle for the MS function.  I note that usleep() was not present in POSIX 2008 and its updates.  Although it is not part of POSIX 2024, the change is older.

@JonathanLeffler I have learned something. Updated. (And thank you!)
